# How to handle few of many simultaneous Web requests in Java Server?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, synchronized

I created a Java Web server with JSP and Servets to handle get/post requests.

If 1000 Web requests hit the server simultaneously,  and I would like to handle the first 10, how would I achieve this? For example, I'd like to run specific code only on the first 10 requests.

What technology would I need to use? Would I need to use synchronized code? Would I need to use thread pools? Would I need to use queues? What is the recommended solution?

Comment: you can use counter in your servlet/jsp in synchronized manner to check that request falls in first 10 or not.

Comment: Maybe explain why you want to only handle the first 10 and not queue the rest. If you really want to do something like that, it's better handled in a proxy-server in front of your app-server, in my opinion.

Comment: A bit confusing to read. Do you want to invoke specific code only on the first 10 requests (say: logging code) and handle all 1000 requests anyway, or do you only want to actually respond to the first 10 requests and drop the 990 other ones?

Comment: @Disco3 I'd like to do this for a payment system. For example, there are 1000 requests but I'd only like to sell a product to the first 10 requests, what would be the best solution? I'd like to have the app respond to the other 990 requests with a simple "not available product" response.

Comment: @Gimby I'd like to do this for a payment system. For example, there are 1000 requests but I'd only like to sell a product to the first 10 requests, what would be the best solution? I'd like to have the app respond to the other 990 requests with a simple "not available product" response.

Comment: To me, that sounds more like "business-logic" or "model" which ideally I wouldn't want in the servlet. "First 10 requests" and"first 10 successful purchases" are two distinct things and lumping them together will make your code less extensible and maintainable. Maybe one of the first 10 requests will fail credit-card validation? I would have separate classes for purchases at the least

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to do this, just use [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) as your counter (the reason behind is that servlets are shared between multiple requests so you could run into synchronization problems). So your code can be something like

```
public HitCounterServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
        int counterValue = counter.incrementAndGet();
        if(value <= 10) {
            // handle request
        }
    }
}
```

You can of course move this code to the [`Filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) or use a proxy server like a @Disco 3 suggested. You could use [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/) for instance.

Comment: Thanks @Petr Mensik I'd like to do this for a payment system. For example, there are 1000 requests but I'd only like to sell a product to the first 10 requests, what would be the best solution? I'd like to have the app respond to the other 990 requests with a simple "not available product" response.    Is using an AtomicInteger the best way to capture the first X requests?